# CSS - Footer won't remain fixed to foot of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm loading a front-end site onto wordpress and on the blog page my footer won't stay fixed to the bottom of the page / wants to float upwards so it ends up looking like this -

[image: Footer floating up the page]

It doesn't do it on the other pages but I've also noticed on Google chrome there's a white strip at the foot of the page also on every page. 
I've looked for solutions via google - majority seem to suggest `position: absolute` but I've tried that and it hasn't worked. This is my code at the moment -

**style.css**

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;

}
```

**footer.php**

```
<!-- footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <div id="socialmedia">
                    <a href="#" class="icon-button twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon-button google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i><span></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon-button instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon-button pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i><span></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">        
                <div id="email">
                    <img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/footer_logo.png" style="width: 150px; height: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px;">  
                    <p>Email: hello@havoccreative.com </br>+971 (0)55 151 0491 or +971 (0)55 282 2114
                    </br>PO Box 769558, twofour54, Abu Dhabi</p>
                    <p>This website was design by us *pause for applause*</br> and built with his bare hands by Michael Whitehead.</br> &copy Havoc Creative 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>        
    </div>  
</footer>       
<!-- /footer -->
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please share your website link.

Comment: @ShitalMarakana It's still on local host at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox can help you! =) Remove position absolute from footer and try this solution:

Step 1: add this to your body element:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Step 2: add this to your footer:

```
footer {
   margin-top: auto;
}
```

Also you can check [this article](http://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) for more ways to create a sticky footer.

Comment: That's done the trick - thanks. But I'm still getting a small gap at the bottom on Chrome - any ideas how I can fix that specifically?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead can't it be <p> tag margin in #email block?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `position` of the `footer` to `fixed` and removing `top: 0` and `right: 0` should do the trick.

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Will this be what's desired when the content is taller than a single screen? The usual desired behaviour is for the footer to be at the bottom of scrollable content if there is enough to be scrollable, but be fixed to the viewport bottom if the content is smaller than the viewport.

Comment: @AgeDeO Hi, sorry this hasn't worked. Well, it's kind of worked for Firefox except it's cut it into a small box in the bottom left hand corner, hasn't done anything for Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @arbuthnott I don't think you can tell on the image above because of the white background but basically the footer is floating up the page and leaving white space underneath when there is insufficient body content to push it down to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies within the fact that you've reserved the space for your footer on `body {}` by setting a margin of 6rem, but not set any off-set for your footer, like `top: 6rem;`.

Don't forget - usually everything goes "inside" `body {}`, for example, like so:

```
<body>
   <header></header>
   <article>
      <left_column></left_column>
      <right_column></right_column>
   </article>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

So, again, to get the effect you want, you have to also off-set the footer position, otherwise you're just "lifting" the whole thing up together. So what you need to do is to modify your **style.css** to look like:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 6rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;

}
```

Another way would be to use `padding-bottom` instead of `margin-bottom` - that way `body` would fill the screen height and leave space for your `footer`, however, you'd have to change `top: 6rem` to something else then.

Comment: Shoot, I was sure I got it right... I probably forgot/missed something. Sadly, I'm not able to fiddle around with this at the given moment, but I'll look into this later today if it won't already be solved/answered by that time. Out of curiosity, what effect have my suggestions achieved? Perhaps try it with `footer { position: absolute;}` ?

Comment: Also, have you checked that `html` isn't applying some additional styling that might be conflicting and causing the undesired effect?

You can also try setting `!important` if you have suspicion that another CSS file might be overriding your changes (like, un-setting off-set).